# Cannot invoke a function that returns a statement

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a function, `sayHello`, which accepts one parameter, `name`. It should return a concatenated string, i.e. "Hello, name".

Here is my code

```
function sayHello(name) {

  return "Hello " + name;
}
return sayHello;
```

When I run `return sayHello`, I see the following:

```
SyntaxError: Illegal return statement
```

When I run `sayHello`:

```
function sayHello(name) {

    return "Hello " + name;
}
sayHello;
```

I see this instead:

```
=> [Function: sayHello]
```

All attempts have lead to errors of one kind or another. I've researched function syntax on MDN, and am fairly certain I've checked the syntax. Would you please point out what I'm missing?

Thank you in advance for all of your help.

--Update: Thanks to Richard Kho, Arun P Johny, hemnath mouli, and Shawn's replies as well as . I really appreciate your help.

The reason this question is different from call a function is that the term, "Call a function," is a key step that I did not know I was supposed to perform, and a key vocabulary term that I did not think to use.

Thanks Again!.

Comment: `return sayHello;` what are you trying to do with that

Comment: Your `sayHello` function is correct... now you just need to invoke it like `var string = sayHello('Chris')` which assign `Hello Chris` to `string`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tq50y99h/1/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a function in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258579/how-to-call-a-function-in-javascript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`return sayHello` is not how you invoke a function in Javascript. Instead, call `sayHello()` and pass it an argument.

Comment: I would also add you do not typically return anything outside a function block, always within one

Answer (score 7):

```
function sayHello(name) {

    return "Hello " + name;
}
alert(sayHello( "Mr. Park" ));
```

Try like this
Output: 
In alert box: `Hello Mr. Park`