# Call a Javascript function and return a response

Tags: javascript

I recently started working with Javascript and I saw this question but there was no explanation for this question. I have the following Javascript code:

```
var A = (function(){
  function Person(name){
    this.name = name;
  }

  var m = function(){
    return "Hello " + this.name;
  };

  Person.prototype.getGreeting = m;

  return Person;
})();
```

What would I have to write so that it can call above code and have it return "Hello World"? I am still learning so pardon my ignorance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a function in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258579/how-to-call-a-function-in-javascript)

Comment: @KernelPanic so it will be A("World"); right?

Comment: Is your ultimate goal to write a hello world program? You can do that in one line: `console.log("Hello world");`

Comment: @qxz no that's not my goal.. I am just trying to understand functions in javascript so basis on my above code it will be called like this `A("World");` right?

Comment: I'll write up an answer

Comment: I'll admit this example is a bit more complex than my suggested duplicate. If @qxz is writing up an answer, I'll retract my flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code defines a `Person` object as `A`, with a constructor that accepts the parameter to print in the "greeting".  So immediately after this code you could write something like:

```
var somePerson = new A('world');
console.log(somePerson.getGreeting());
```

This would create an instance of `A` (which wraps `Person`) in a variable called `somePerson` and would log the output of `getGreeting()` on that instance.

With a little more consistent spacing and indentation you can see the structure more clearly.  [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/n034sm6h/).

Answer (score 2):

You can start simple and build up to the full example:

```
function Person(name){
  this.name = name;
}

var m = function(){
  return "Hello " + this.name;
};

Person.prototype.getGreeting = m;

var p = new Person('anybody');

console.log(p.getGreeting());
```

If you are coming from another programming language, a good book to get started with is "JavaScript: The Good Parts" by Douglas Crockford. After that, a good read is "Effective JavaScript" by David Herman. Those will answer your questions about the code example better than any of our answers here.

Answer (score 1):

```js
    var A=(function(){
      function Person(name){
        this.name=name;
      }
      var m=function(){
        return"Hello "+this.name;
      };

      Person.prototype.getGreeting=m;

      return Person;
    })();

    var B = new A();
    B.name = "World";
    console.log(B.getGreeting());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new A("World").getGreeting()
```

The definition of A creates a function and then immediately calls it. The function creates another function called Person. This function is a JavaScript constructor and can be used to create a new object via "new Person". The Person constructor accepts a name parameter and stores it internally. It also sets the getGreeting member of the Person function's prototype to a function that prints "Hello" followed by the name of the Person.

To use, do new A("World") to call the constructor A (which is really Person), passing in World, then call the getGreeting method of the resulting object, which will invoke the getGreeting function of the prototype.

Answer (score 0):

Your code uses an idiom called an [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript), which keeps the variables/functions `Person` and `m` private/hidden inside the scope of that anonymous function. You then immediately call the anonymous function, which sets up the `Player` class and then returns it. The result (the `Player` constructor itself) gets stored in `A`. *(JavaScript doesn't actually have classes, but that's another discussion.)*

To create an instance of this class, you'd do something like:

```
var joe = new A("Joe");
```

Then you could use the `joe` object (an instance of the `Person`/`A` class):

```
console.log(joe.getGreeting()); // Hello Joe
```

Full working example:

```js
var A = (function(){
  function Person(name){
    this.name = name;
  }

  var m = function(){
    return "Hello " + this.name;
  };

  Person.prototype.getGreeting = m;

  return Person;
})();

var joe = new A("Joe");

console.log(joe.getGreeting());
```